# How to get the .plt address when i have the GOT_OFFSET_TABLE？

Tags: reverse-engineering, elf, bin

When I test to reconstruct the elf executable from process image, i got the .dynamic and `GOT_OFFSET_TABLE`,but The global offset table was  filled in with the resolved values of the corresponding shared library functions.I must replace these addresses with the original `PLT` stub addresses. So,how can I get the `PLT` stub addresses from a process image.

```
for(c=0;dyn[c].d_tag !=DT_NULL ;c++){
        switch (dyn[c].d_tag){
            case DT_PLTGOT:
                got = (Elf64_Addr)dyn[c].d_un.d_ptr;
                printf("[+]Located plt.got vaddr:0x%x\n",got);
                printf("[+]Relevant GOT entries begin at 0x%x\n", (Elf64_Addr)dyn[c].d_un.d_ptr + 24);

                got_off = dyn[c].d_un.d_ptr - h.data_vaddr;

                GOT_TABLE = (Elf64_Addr*)&pmem[h.data_offset +got_off];
                GOT_TABLE += 3;
                break;
         ...
}
Elf64_Addr PLT_VADDR = ?

gdb-peda$ x/10gx  0x601000 + 3*8
0x601018:   0x00007f3eaf557800  0x00007f3eaf522740    0x601018->GOT_OFFSET_TABLE[3]
0x601028:   0x00007f3eaf578160  0x0000000000000000
0x601038:   0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x601048:   0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x601058:   0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we're reading the same book, 'Learning Linux Binary Analysis' and stuck on the same exercise. I did not find an elegant way to retrieve the `.plt` address but you may be able to find it by using `ElfN_Shdr.sh_name` and by doing a `strcmp(ElfN_Shdr.sh_name, '.plt')` on it.

The author, `elfmaster` seems to be using that :

https://github.com/elfmaster/ftrace/blob/master/ftrace.c#L418

Comment: After some testing I cannot access Section Header Table while the program is being run, it appears that this part of the ELF is not mapped(unrelevant for execution?) into the memory ?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed do get my way out to `.plt` address on a stripped binary compiled with PIE(Process Independent Execution). I observed that the .plt section was always on top of .text section.

By substracting the rel relocation table size, stored in `DT_RELSZ`, to the entry point, `e_entry`, you can get the address of `.plt`. I do not know yet if it coincidence and that this trick is actually garbage but it works.

I checked multiples elfparser and it seems that they are all using section name(sh_name) to identify .plt section. We're asked to recover an ELF file in memory and it appears that section headers are only relevant for linking and not loaded for execution but I'm not sure and you should double checked that.